# Group By for a Window function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am stuck in a scenario where I have prices along with date and product id and am running windows functions on top of the prices.

What am looking for is that the output should be one row per day with the aggregation and the window functions. Because the source data has multiple rows per day and am using the aggregation and window function to clear that.

When am doing group by it says I have to add prices.

Why is that?

```
select
  product_id,
  DATE(fetch_datetime_utc) AS date,
  marketplace,
  source,
  avg(list_price) OVER(
            PARTITION by asin, date
            ORDER BY date
        ) AS list_price,
  avg(price) OVER(
            PARTITION by asin, date
            ORDER BY date
        ) AS price,
  min(price) OVER(
            PARTITION by asin, date
            ORDER BY date
        ) AS min_price,
  max(price) OVER(
            PARTITION by asin, date
            ORDER BY date
        ) AS max_price
from
  table1
group by
  productid,
  DATE(fetch_datetime_utc),
  marketplace
```

Comment: You need to communicate the intention of your code with some sample data and expected output. The gist of your problem is 2 things-- all non-aggregated columns in `select` clause must be present in `group by` AND `window functions` are applied on the output of `group by`.  Due to that fact, you'll get the same error for asin column as well. Again, without sample data and expected output, it's hard to tell if you should include these column in the `group by` first or slap aggregations on them before applying the `window function`

Comment: @PhilCoulson Ive updated the description. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your window functions should not have ORDER BY clauses as min/max/avg do not do anything with ORDERED data.

But the core problem is that using this form of these functions calculates answer be row. At which point the whole blocks group by does not know which row value to use, you could wrap the 4 functions in an ANY_VALUE() but then given the partition by does not match the group by clauses you will get random results.

Also `source` is missing from your group by's.

I also assume asin and product_id are aligned.. and would suggest you just use this SQL instead:

```
select
  product_id,
  DATE(fetch_datetime_utc) AS date,
  marketplace,
  source,
  avg(list_price) AS list_price,
  avg(price) AS price,
  min(price) AS min_price,
  max(price) AS max_price
from table1
group by 1,2,3,4
```